# Undefined offset & Uninitialized string offset log errors

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting below **log** errors in custom module

**a**.Notice: **Undefined offset**: 2 in line `if($commodity_name[2] != "") {`

**b**.Notice: **Undefined offset**: 3 & Notice: **Uninitialized string offset**: 2 in line `if($commodity_name[3] != "") {`

**c**.Notice: **Undefined offset**: 1 & Notice: **Uninitialized string offset**: 3  in `if($commodity_name[1] != "") {`

```
<?php
    if($CommodityDetail1 == "") {
        if($commodity_name[1] != "") {
            $CommodityDetail1 = $commodity_name[1];
            $Commoditypid1 = $commodity_id_change[1];
        }
    }
?>

<label>Cmdty Detail 1</label><input class="removenamebypid_<?php echo $Commoditypid1 ?>" style="width:100px" type="text" id="service_cmdtydetail1" name="service_cmdtydetail1" value="product1" maxlength="3000" />
<input type="hidden" value="product" id="addnamebypid_<?php echo $Commoditypid1 ?>" />

<?php
    if($CommodityDetail2 == "") {
        if($commodity_name[2] != "") {
            $CommodityDetail2 = $commodity_name[2];
            $Commoditypid2 = $commodity_id_change[2];
        }
    }
?>
<label>Cmdty Detail 2</label><input class="removenamebypid_<?php echo $Commoditypid2 ?>" style="width:100px" type="text" id="service_cmdtydetail2" name="service_cmdtydetail2" value="product2" maxlength="3000"/>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $CommodityDetail2; ?>" id="addnamebypid_<?php echo $Commoditypid2 ?>" />

<?php
    if($CommodityDetail3 == "") {
        if($commodity_name[3] != "") {
            $CommodityDetail3 = $commodity_name[3];
            $Commoditypid3 = $commodity_id_change[3];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: if anyone want full code, here : https://pastebin.com/pViyePDW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved issue :

```
if( !isset($commodity_name[2]) ) $commodity_name[2] = '' ;
if( !isset($commodity_name[1]) ) $commodity_name[1] = '' ;
if( !isset($commodity_name[3]) ) $commodity_name[3] = '' ;
```

Comment: if anyone have better solution, please post here......